# proof - if in inner product space $(\alpha , \beta )= 0$ for all $\beta \in V$ then show that $\alpha = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Here is my approach
if this holds, $( \alpha , \alpha ) = 0 $ then $\alpha = 0$. But there can be another vector for $\alpha$ so that above equation holds. I mean in mapping 
$$ V\times V \longrightarrow  F,$$ 2 points in domain may point to 0 in F. One such point is the O vector in V. OR is that there is 1-1 mapping between $$V\times V \longrightarrow F$$ (ensures that 1 point in F has 1 pre-image in domain). Pls clarify

Comment: No, the mapping from VXV  to F defined by (u, v)--> (u, v) is NOT, in general, one-to-one.  For one thing, if v is any unit vector then <v, v>= 1.  However, one of the conditions for an inner product is "$(v, v)\ge 0$ and (v, v)= 0 if and only if v= 0"

Comment: as it is not , in general, 1-1 , how can i say that some other vector in V (some non zero vector) satisfies above equation. { can we have this kind of setup:- (0, v) = 0  for all v in V and (p , v) = 0 in which p non-zero vector in V. I am slightly confused here. Pls enlighten

Comment: No, this cannot happen: any vector **uniquely** determines a linear function. If $0$ acts like $p$ on the whole vector space, then they are the same. And you have proven this

Answer (score 3):

Just take $\beta=\alpha$ and use one of the axioms of inner products.

Answer (score 0):

In this exercise $\alpha$ is fixed. So you are considering the map
$$
\beta \mapsto \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle
$$
You should think of $\alpha$ as a linear map rather than a vector (so as an element in the dual space). If a linear map is zero everywhere than it is zero as a point in the dual space and the vector that represents it is zero (simply follow your explanation).

If you consider the scalar product, then you have a **bilinear** map
$$
\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : V \times V \to F.
$$

Of course this map has many zeros (any two orthogonal vectors), but it is not what you are looking for.

Also the map
$$
\beta \mapsto \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle
$$

has many zeros, namely the orthogonal complement of $\alpha.$

The only map that *does not have many zeros*, i.e. is one-to-one is the map that associates any vector to a function (namely the linear map above). Your calculation shows that this map in injective.

Comment: How would you show that there exists a *unique* vector which represents a
 linear functional without using $x \perp V \implies x = 0$? Without it you cannot conclude that the zero functional is represented only by the vector $0$.

Comment: I don't do it without this fact. I just refer to it first as "your explanation" and then as "your calculation", because in the question this is already proven in the first sentence IMO.

Comment: But then you could just set $\beta = \alpha$ in the first place.

Comment: The author of the question already set $\beta = \alpha$ in the first sentence, he asked for a clarification and not a proof. I wanted to explain why this does not contradict the fact that the bilinear map has many zeros.

Comment: I am novice trying to learn things. Keeping aside complex notations, My understanding is as 
consider V,V as x axis and y axis which are both vector spaces. Output or range as another real number line. Problem is equivalent to - 
find x such that xy = 0 for y on y-axis. 
as it is numbers, above equation means x = 0. 
But in case of Z12 we can have 3*4 = 0; .... 6*2 =0

Comment: I believe that $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is not a field, and that $F$ is supposed to be one. Furthermore scalar products are defined on vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ usually, since otherwise you would not have the notion of positivity.